# Convert Date Time to MySql timestamp

Tags: php

I've set of dates that look like this `Sat, 16 Apr 2016 16:29:06 +0000`

Who can I convert them to MySql timestamp format using PHP?

Answer (score 2):

```
$timestamp = $date_time->getTimestamp();
```

documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.gettimestamp.php

Comment: I want the mysql timestamp as like 2016-04-12 12:52:20 not unix timestamp :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method of Datetime

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
?>
```

output

```
2000-01-01 00:00:00
```

Or else you can try [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function of PHP

```
<?php
    $date = "now";//Date in any common format
    echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($date))   
?>
```

Note* In above example I am using [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function to convert string date to PHP timestamp

output

`2016-04-20 07:14:46`